# Stream multiple files from folder using vlcj

Tags: java, file, stream, directory, vlcj

```
    public void Stream(String FOLDER_PATH, int port){        

    File myDir = new File(FOLDER_PATH);
    File[] files = myDir.listFiles(); 

    if( myDir.exists() && myDir.isDirectory()){               
       do {                  
          System.out.println(files[i]+" ...");
          //File myFile = new File(files[i].getPath());                  
          mediaPlayer.playMedia(files[i].getPath(), 
          ":sout=#rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port="+String.valueOf(port) +",mux=ts}",
          ":no-sout-rtp-sap", 
          ":no-sout-standard-sap", 
          ":sout-all", 
          ":sout-keep"
          ); 

          i++;

          }while(i< files.length && mediaPlayer.isMediaParsed());
      }    
}
```

How can I modify this code to make vlcj play(stream) the next file in folder after the current one ends?

I tried different methods but it stops after the first file.

Comment: Your iteration variable `i` doesn't seemed to be initialized.

Comment: I initialized it in the beginning, as a global variable..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to VLC sample `uk.co.caprica.vlcj.test.list.TestMediaListEmbeddedPlayer` from `vlcj-1.2.0-test.jar` distribution, this is how it is done:

```
/**
 * Example showing how to combine a media list player with an embedded media
 * player.
 */
public class TestMediaListEmbeddedPlayer extends VlcjTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
        CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface = mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas);

        EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);

        MediaListPlayer mediaListPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newMediaListPlayer();

        mediaListPlayer.addMediaListPlayerEventListener(new MediaListPlayerEventAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void nextItem(MediaListPlayer mediaListPlayer, libvlc_media_t item, String itemMrl) {
                System.out.println("nextItem()");
            }
        });

        mediaListPlayer.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer); // <--- Important, associate the media player with the media list player

        JPanel cp = new JPanel();
        cp.setBackground(Color.black);
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("vlcj embedded media list player test");
        f.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(TestMediaListEmbeddedPlayer.class.getResource("/icons/vlcj-logo.png")).getImage());
        f.setContentPane(cp);
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

        MediaList mediaList = mediaPlayerFactory.newMediaList();
        String[] options = {};
        mediaList.addMedia("C:\\Documents and Settings\\DEVELOPER\\Desktop\\videoplayback1.mp4", options);
        mediaList.addMedia("C:\\Documents and Settings\\DEVELOPER\\Desktop\\videoplayback2.mp4", options);

        mediaListPlayer.setMediaList(mediaList);
        mediaListPlayer.setMode(MediaListPlayerMode.LOOP);

        mediaListPlayer.play();

        // This looping is just for purposes of demonstration, ordinarily you would
        // not do this of course
        for(;;) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            mediaPlayer.setChapter(3);

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            mediaListPlayer.playNext();
        }

        //    mediaList.release();
        //    mediaListPlayer.release();
        //    mediaPlayer.release();
        //    mediaPlayerFactory.release();
    }
}
```